# Perl Loop not filtering right results

Tags: perl, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, scripting

Why does my while loop seem to be missing some match values?
This result output is not returning all the possible values after reading the files. There are some missing values.

```
# str_1,2,3,4 are my search strings 

while ($line = <$fh>) {

    if ( $line !~ /$str_1/ && $line =~ /$str_2/ ) {
        open($fh, '>>report.txt');
        print $fh "$file : $line";
        close $fh;
    }

    if ( $line !~ /$str_3/ && $line =~ /$str_4/ ) {  
        open($fh, '>>report.txt');
        print $fh "$file : $line";  
        close $fh;
    } 
}
```

output:

```
Number of Attendance = 1 INFO:21
Number of Attendance = 2 INFO:21
Number of Attendance = 1 INFO:21 

# There are results such as Number of Attendance = 8 INFO:21 which my code is not able to search.
```

For example:

```
     #my log file which is the input
    Number of Attendance = 1 from XYZ FACI     INFO:21
    Number of Attendance = 0 from UZQ BLAH     INFO:21
    Number of Attendance = 8 from WZW BLAH     INFO:21
    Number of Attendance = 0 from WZW BLAH     INFO:21
    Number of Attendance = 0 from WZW BLAH     INFO:21
    Number of Attendance = 0 from WZW BLAH     INFO:21

   so here my str1 = /Number of Attendance = 0/
              str2 = /INFO:21/

   #So output for my code now is only

    Number of Attendance = 1 from XYZ FACI     INFO:21

  #But,Expected output should be

   Number of Attendance = 1 from XYZ FACI     INFO:21
   Number of Attendance = 8 from WZW BLAH     INFO:21
```

I think its only reading all my files only once and returning the first output value instead  of returning all the possible values.

Comment: Can you please explicitly mention the input, expected output and the output this code is giving?

Comment: Because the pattern in `$str1` matches or the pattern in `$str_2` doesn't, and because the pattern in `$str3` matches or the pattern in `$str_4`  doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the filehandle that you are trying to iterate over!

If you had `use warnings;` in your code, perl would have warned you:

`readline() on closed filehandle $fh at /home/felix/abdc/foo.pl line 9.`

**Always** `use warnings;` and `use strict;`

Rewrite your while loop like this:

```
open my $fh, "<$file" or die "Unable to open '$file' : $!";
open my $out, ">output_log" or die "Unable to open 'output_log' : $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ( ... ) {
        print $out $line;
    }
    ...
}
close $out or die "Unable to finish writing output_log : $!";
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! But I found out that the condition works properly. But it only fetches first result and not able check for further lines on the file.                          Please check above example on the question @xxfelixxx

Comment: Try changing the name of the variable from `$fh` to `$fh_log` inside your while loop.  You might be closing the file handle you are trying to iterate over, which would cut you off after 1 match.